# Jasper server subreport in detail band

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need to create subreports in detail band, i am passing same datasource of main report to subreports.
Issue i am facing as it goes in to subreport it increments the index counter which does not allow to add remaining subreport.

*MainReport.jrxml*

```
<group name="Account Summary">
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{accountSummary.hasRepots}]]></printWhenExpression>
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement x="28" y="0" width="540" height="100" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <subreportParameter name="accountSummary">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{accountSummary.hasRepots}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "SubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

*SubReport.jrxml*

```
<detail>
    <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport isUsingCache="false">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="540" height="100" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + $F{subreportFileName}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Where i pass $F{subreportFileName} from my datasource for example "SubSubReport.jrxml", but it only displays first report, i guess due to my index counter runs out in my sub-sub report so my sub report detail band doesn't go for each element.

*SubSubReport.jrxml*

```
<field name="chartData.label" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="chartData.value" class="java.lang.Float"/>
<field name="value1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="value2" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="value3" class="java.lang.String"/>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="114" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="lbl-light-golden" x="12" y="19" width="170" height="67"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="26"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Some Label]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <pieChart>
            <chart evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement x="272" y="0" width="268" height="114"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                <chartLegend position="Left"/>
            </chart>
            <pieDataset>
                <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{chartData.label}]]></keyExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{chartData.value}]]></valueExpression>
                <labelExpression><![CDATA[null]]></labelExpression>
            </pieDataset>
            <piePlot isShowLabels="false" isCircular="true">
                <plot/>
                <itemLabel/>
            </piePlot>
        </pieChart>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="540" height="1"/>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="lbl-black-table-header" x="12" y="4" width="158" height="14"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[Header 1]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="lbl-black-table-header" x="205" y="4" width="199" height="14"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Header 2]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="lbl-black-table-header" x="445" y="4" width="74" height="13"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Header 3]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="17" width="540" height="1"/>
        </line>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="12" y="1" width="158" height="16"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="205" y="1" width="199" height="16"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font isStrikeThrough="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="445" y="1" width="74" height="16"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value3}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Also i tried using Groups instead of detail band as follows in "SubReport.jrxml"

*SubReport.jrxml*

```
<group name="Sub report 1">
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="540" height="100" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "SubSubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<group name="Sub report 2">
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="200" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="110" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Sub report 2]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="40" width="540" height="100" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "SubSubReport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

It prints "Sub report 2" label but no success with printing "SubSubReport1.jasper"

What am i doing wrong any suggestions or any direction which can help.

Comment: I am experiencing same issue... I wanted to pass data which is list to my sub report and subreport display in table. what I have to do.?

Answer (score 1):

the report data source should never be used to feed a subreport. The REPORT_DATA_SOURCE is a data source that is a consumable object.

This means that is usable for feeding a report only once. Therefore, the parameter technique is not suitable when every record of the master report has its own subreport (unless there is only one record in the master report). I think this could be the reason that you see only one.